# Use trigger to calculate difference between rows in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, triggers

Given a table structure like this:

`ID|Measurement|Diff|Date`

where `ID` and `Date` is the composite primary key, and rows are further indexed by the `Date` column.

I want to use a trigger (after an `insert or replace into`) to calculate the `Diff` column for the table. The `Diff` column simply records the differences in the values of `Measurement` between two adjacent dates for the same `ID`.

What is the optimal way of doing this in SQLite? Performance is crucial here, since the table is large, i.e. 1M+ rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query to calculate the value should be something like this:

```
update structure
    set new.diff = new.measurement - (select s.measurement
                                      from structure s
                                      where date < new.date
                                      order by date desc
                                      limit 1)
    where id = new.id;
```

The `update` should use the primary key index to quickly identify the row.  The subquery should use the `date` index to quickly find the previous row.  So, this should have reasonable performance.

Comment: thank you for the answer. Just a question on the sub-query part where you select the `measurement` of the previous date, can we specify a condition for `id` there instead of specifying at the level of the update statement? If so, I wonder if there is any difference in performance. This is for my own understanding. Thanks.

Comment: @skyork . . . You can specify whatever condition you like.  For the example above, an index on `date` would be recommended for performance reasons.